# Laravel, routes

Tags: php, laravel

this is my simple routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});


Route::get('results',array('uses'=>'AutonomoController@mostrarAutonomos'));
```

I enter in Public/results url, he return an error:
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

If I change the "results" route to "/" work fine.

I had a error with /results, "not found", but i read that is necessary active the mod_rewriter, but when i active it, result is de other error.

When active debug mode, the error is:
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

```
 if (!is_null($route)) {
            return $route->bind($request);
        }
        $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
        if (count($others) > 0) {
            return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
        }
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(); 
    }
    protected function checkForAlternateVerbs($request)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Please check the language!

Comment: Try `/public/index.php/results`

Comment: in `app/config/app.php` turn `debug` to `true`.

Comment: Ok, first excuse my english ;). I try public/index.php/results, and work fine, but no without 'index.php'

Comment: That means something with the .htaccess rewriting is not working correctly. Check if you have [this .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) in your public directory and that mod_rewrite is working properly

Comment: Yes, i have .htaccess like your, and i think that mod_rewrite work fine. Are active in apache. I change AllowOverride to all, and delete "#" on mod.

Comment: You can try [this .htaccess](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls) instead

Comment: I have the same error with this htaccess. :(